# How can I tidy up an auto increment field in a table from within a module?

Tags: database, theming

How can I tidy up an auto increment field in a table from within a module, so that a table like this (the 'id' field being auto incrementing):

```
id title
1  foo
3  bar
7  fee
```

becomes:

```
id title
1  foo
2  bar
3  fee
```

Is there a function, like serial_field_tidy or something?

Answer (score 1):

You should never do that since the IDs are important for addressing to that specific row in other tables. You would never know which modules are also indexed this row with its id. So if you change the ID of a row, you will encounter unexpected things in your installation.

Comment: Okay, thanks, as a general rule, but this table is from my own schema and I know it is not used by any other modules so it wouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: I mean no offence, but if the design of your app relies in some way on sequential identifiers in a database table, there's something not quite right. A function like `serial_field_tidy` doesn't exist because it's considered bad practice to attempt to do what you're trying to do. The logic isn't terribly difficult (you could probably do it in a single SQL statement), but I'd recommend examining the _requirement_ that's led you to this conclusion before you go ahead with it

Comment: No offence taken, it's a fair point.

Answer (score 0):

There's another option more easy, with views you can show a field with global usage (I'm not sure the name of this option) and print his row number or his row number plus 1st ID

But like other people told you, avoid change IDs